# Ubuntu Core 18 - How to update the SSH Key at runtime

Tags: ssh

My question is about the ssh keys registration process in Ubuntu core 18. The ssh key get downloaded at the time of installation. What would be the solution if someone has update the SSH key?
If not, then how the remote device get logged in?
Is there any other possible way to alternatively register, update delete ssh keys in Ubuntu account. Problem comes when we have to scale up the number of devices and avoid tedious task to register all devices by generating ssh keys and registering in account.

Comment: Which "ssh keys"? System, or User?

Comment: ssh keys on system gets register in user account. So how to do this while scaling (increasing the count of devices) or on run time.